# Is there any easy way to create AJAX query after timeout in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, razor

Of course, we can do it with Javascript.
But maybe there is solution like that:
`@Ajax.TimeoutRequest("Action", Timeout, ...)`

Maybe there is some library for such task?

Comment: Can You please reword Your question? Need some more description why do You need it and where exactly this library could fit into your requirements?